# changing a header based on an unordered list's <li> list item's active class

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, forms

I'm creating a multi-step form using jquery (got the code [here](http://thecodeplayer.com/walkthrough/jquery-multi-step-form-with-progress-bar)), but I wanted to customize it a bit and add a header at the top.

```
    <header>Profile Settings
        <div class="wayfinder">
            <ul id="progressbar">
                <li class="active">Step 1</li>
                <li>Step 2</li>
                <li>Step 3</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </header>
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/co5u6n9r/1/

Can someone help explain how I can change the title (Profile Settings) when it goes to the next step? I'm guessing that it has to do with the list item's active class, but I can't figure out what the first step is. Or is there a better solution to this?

Comment: Firstly, wrap "Profile Settings" in a text tag so that JQ has something to select...bare text nodes like that are hard to select. Once you've  done that you can use the `.html` function in jQuery to change it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

done it inside your fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/co5u6n9r/3/

first of all, i wrapped the header inside an h1 tag, so i get a selectable element. in css, i changed the header definition to header h1, to match the new element structure.
then, i added the following two lines to your previous and next functions:

```
newHeadline = "Profile Step " + $("fieldset").index(next_fs);
$("header h1").html(newHeadline);

newHeadline = "Profile Step " + $("fieldset").index(previous_fs);
$("header h1").html(newHeadline);
```

the value of newHeadline would be the new Title. in my example, i use "profile step" with  your form step index. but of course, this can be literally everything...